# Remove data based on unique month-day combinations

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I currently have data from the 2018-01-01 to 2019-06-30 and I need to do a Year-to-Date comparison between 2018 and 2019. (Data gets summed).

As such, I need to remove from my dataset data from 2018-07-01 to 2018-12-12 as I should only use data for a year if it exists in the previous year.

I can almost get what I want with the code below, except that gets me all of 2018 which is undesirable.

```
df.groupby(df.TimeStamp.dt.year).agg(sum)
```

Would you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: What about filtering these dates before grouping by?

Comment: That's what I would like to do Thales, but the data is not static. Every week more data is added onto it. I can get the latest date from df.TimeStamp.max() but I need to find a way to get that date, minus a year and then remove everything from that date to 01-01-current-year. Timedelta won't work as a year is not a unit of time so the alternatives I could find would be to either use relativedelta or construct the TimeStamp as a string.